# C# Reflection - Consuming a dll in other machine

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to use some methods from a DLL (.Net compiled), but this DLL is not in my machine, it's inside a Client machine (away from me).

The problem is, I need a way to call this dll through a C# application and this dll will do something in the client machine.

I have heard about Reflection, but I don't know if can be used to consume the dll in other machine that is not on my network.

Thank You

Comment: In what way(s) can you connect the two machines?

Comment: @BanksySan, the server machine is in one city and the client's machine is in other city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Ask the client to send you a copy of the dll

Or

2- Expose the ddl methods needed as a web service.

Comment: Hello Oscar, i have tested this dll locally and works fine, but i need to call that dll to do the same thing(call printer's commands to be executed over client machine).

Comment: @Maturano So? What is your question? As I said, use it locally or ask your customer to expose it's methods as a web service.

Comment: i guess the only way is your second approach. By the way, thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Look for the proxy design pattern. You will have to write some code to access it over the internet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Comment: i will take a look in this proxy design pattern. Thank you @Mostaguen

Comment: No problem. When you face a problem like yours just tell yourself that someone else already faced that problem. I suggest you to get a book on design patterns. Knowing them greatly improve your programming and allow you to easily fix these sort of problems :)